# How to do Authentication/Authorization

Tags: reactjs, flutter, security, authentication, authorization

I want to create an applicaiton that will consist of a React app, a Flutter mobile app and a backend REST API that will be called by the front end apps. I want to add authentication to the two client apps and authorization to the API.

I have been reading on this topic for the last few days and I cannot seem to find a way that is both secure and UX friendly. I have checked a few technlogies/providers (Ory, Keycloak, Auth0 and IdentityServer) and my problem with all of them is that they redirect you to another url which for the React would be more acceptable. However, for the mobile app this will either pop-up the in-app browser or straight up redirect you to your browser and that is just bad UX in mind. Only Auth0 mention the possibility of an embedded login but I could not find an example and their flutter sdk is badly documented(it is not even listed on their website).

I would like the flow to be:

1. User opens app
2. User is presented with a log in page
3. User fills in credentials and logs in

My question is: How can I do this? My knowledge about authentication/authorization is very limited so any pointers will be welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make the whole experience more integrated with Chrome Custom Tabs etc. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091322/can-i-use-authorization-code-with-pkce-flow-for-mobile-app As pointed out in that answer, you don't really have a choice about using the browser because the IAM needs to be able to do more than a simple username/password form. It needs to be able to show you any 2FA questions, password reset, security questions etc etc - and that needs a browser. (As noted in the linked answer, password flow is deprecated.)

Comment: Also see: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth

Answer (score 0):

```
const Home = lazy(() =>
    import ("../containers/home/Home")
);
```

Here i importing container using lazy

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} isAuth={isUserLoggedIn} />
```

here i am makeing a route using the countainer and i am passing `isUserLoggedIn` redux state i am setting while logging in

and below is my private route code

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuth, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (isAuth) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/page_not_found",
                state: {
                  from: props.location,
                },
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

i am using `react-router-dom` for doing this

Answer (score 0):

When you are building a mobile app, you will always have to open a browser window - if the flow is OAuth2.0 based.
With Ory Kratos this is not the case however, since the flow is cookie-based.
Check out this step-by-step guide how to implement it:
https://www.ory.sh/login-react-native-authentication-example-api/